# SVG Circle Element Cx Cy R

Tags: html, css, svg

I was using SVGcircleElement.cx (cy and r) and I started to write it in my main **CSS** this way :

```
circle{
    cx: 50;
    cy: 50;
    r: 20;
    fill: none;
    stroke: var(--white);
    stroke-width: 3;
}
```

But I figured out is was not working in Mozilla, so I put it in the **html** this way and it is working perfectly everywhere :

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/>
```

However as I have multiple circle I would love to use css and not repeat my self many time in html. Does anybody know how to write it to make it works ? (I already try `moz-cx: 50;` but obviously it was not working)

Comment: first you need to add the `svg` tag if you need helps, then I think some SVG attribute don't have CSS equivalent.

Comment: You'd need to download the source code to Firefox and [fix it to support this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1383650).

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to do that ?

Comment: @Grms in that case you'll have to stick to attributes.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat yourself you may use the `<use>` element. In your case add an `id` to the circle (for example `id="theCircle`) and then you can reuse it like this: `<use xlink:href = "#theCircle">` You can also place it in a different position if you add a `x` and/or `y` attribute to the `<use>` element.

Comment: @exaneta the overhead of <use> elements is such that you're really better off just drawing multiple shapes unless you need the synchronisation of <use> i.e. change the template changes all the instances.